# What is a pointer to an array of x amount of ints?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've been working through *C++ Primer*, and I feel as if something hasn't been explained clearly...

I understand what it means to have a array of pointers to `int`s, for example:

```
int *foo [4];
```

or

```
int *foo1 [2][4];
```

However, I don't understand what it means to have a pointer to an *array* of some number of `int`s. Here's an example from the book:

```
int ia[3][4];
int (*p) [4] = ia;
```

What is `p` here, and what does this mean, both in the 1D and the 2D case?

Comment: Life time advice: Always use proper variable names. Ex: IntArray, MyPointer, My2dArray.. etc

Comment: I assume these variable names are shortened for representation purposes only, as these examples come from the book c++ primer, however, I totally agree with what you are saying 100%

Comment: It is impossible to get a pointer to the array. Arrays almost always decay to pointer to their first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a variable like

```
int array[137];
```

the type of the variable `array` is `int[137]`; that is, an array of 137 `int`s. In C++, you can create pointers or references to variables of any type that you'd like, so you can create a pointer to the variable `array`. Since `array` has type "array of 137 `int`s," a pointer to `array` would have type "pointer to an array of 137 `int`s." The syntax for writing out a pointer like this would be

```
int (*arrayPtr)[137] = &array;
```

This is read as "`arrayPtr` is a pointer, and what it points at is an array of 137 `int`s." The syntax here is unusual, but that's what you would do if you wanted a pointer to an array of 137 integers.

Similarly, you could make a *reference* to `array` like this:

```
int (&arrayRef)[137] = array;
```

It's extremely uncommon to see pointers to arrays actually used anywhere - I've never seen it done except in very specialized template circumstances. *References* to arrays are sometimes used in template programming, but otherwise I've never seen them used anywhere before.

In other words, it's good to know these exist and know how to read them, but realistically you're unlikely to need them unless you start doing some pretty advanced library development or like to play around with template wizardry.

This gets weirder when you factor array-to-pointer decay into the mix. The example code you had was essentially

```
int myArray[137][42];
int (*arrayPtr)[42] = myArray;
```

The type of `arrayPtr` is "pointer to an array of 42 `int`s", which is of type `int (*) [42]`. So why can we assign `myArray`, which has type `int[137][42]`, to it? This is where *array-to-pointer decay* kicks in. Array-to-pointer decay is an implicit conversion that converts an array to a pointer to its first element. Let's see how that applies here.

`myArray` is an array of 137 arrays of 42 integers. This can be though of as "an array of 137 things, each of which is an `int[42]`." This means that when array-to-pointer decay applies to `myArray`, it converts to a pointer to its first element. That element is itself an array of 42 integers, so the effect of applying the array-to-pointer decay is that the expression `myArray` implicitly converts to an `int (*) [42]` (a pointer to an array of 42 integers), specifically, one pointing at the first row in the array.

The net effect of this assignment is that `arrayPtr` now points to the first of the 137 arrays in `myArray`. This is just plain weird, if you ask me, and I would not advise writing code like this. I've been writing C++ for years and never had the misfortune of seeing this used anywhere, so I think it's safe to chalk this one up to "bizarre edge cases that only library implementers need to worry about." :-)

Comment: @SergeyA Are you sure about that? I believe I've seen this used before. I know that "it compiles" is a lousy justification for something like this, but this does compile at ideone.com: http://ideone.com/0olpbL

Comment: Yes, it compiles. But you end up with a pointer to first element.

Comment: @SergeyA When you take the address of an array, you do end up with a pointer to the array as an object. There's an independent concept of array-to-pointer decay, but that's not what applies here.

Comment: @SergeyA you are absolutely wrong. There are pointers to arrays. You can check this easily.

Comment: @davmac, yes, I seem to be in the wrong here. I was somehow sure you can't take an address of the array. My bad.

Comment: @SergeyA I updated my answer with an explanation as to what the code in the OP's question is doing. It's actually pretty cool - it uses array pointers in conjunction with array-to-pointer decay in a way that I've never seen used before in all my years of writing C++ code. Just goes to show you that no matter how much C++ you've seen, you've never seen it all. :-)

Comment: @SergeyA no problem, there is a lot of confusion in this area, probably because arrays decay to pointers in nearly all contexts.

Comment: Thanks! Very detailed answer that definitely clears up the confusion in this area. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

```
int (*p) [4];
```

means

`p` is a pointer to an array of 4 int elements.

*By bracket overriding rule, pointer `*` has higher precedence over array `[]` in this case. So, `p` is at first a pointer.*

Answer (score 0):

```
int ia[3][4];
int (*p) [4] = ia;
```

Basically here p will hold the starting address of each row of the ia matrix.

```
p[0] = &ia[0];
...
```